# The difference between split() and split('') in python

Tags: python

Does anyone know why there is a difference between a split funcion without any arguments and one using white space as argument in Python 3.9.7?

```
s = "1  2 3  4 5 6   "
print(s.split())
# prints ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

print(s.split(' '))
# prints ['1', '', '2', '3', '', '4', '5', '6', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? Maybe Python version? In 3.7.9 "1 2 3".split(" ") gives ['1', '2', '3']

Comment: Is it possible that `s` has more than one space between some numbers?

Comment: Does your actual input have multiple spaces? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: That code does not produce that output.  Please show us the real code.

Comment: The only way your example would work the way you say it should is if `s = "1  2 3  4 5 6    "`

Comment: Even in Python2 the behavior of `split` is as others explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `split()` behavior treats multiple adjacent whitespaces as if they are just one space.

`split(' ')` does not do that.

Comment: The input in the OP's question does not have multiple adjacent whitespaces. This seems to be a correct answer for a different question. If it did, it would be a dupe. This should probably be closed as "needs debugging help" without reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

*string.split(separator, maxsplit)*

**separator**
Optional. Specifies the separator to use when splitting the string.
**By default**, any whitespace is a separator

**maxsplit**
Optional. Specifies how many splits to do. Default value is -1, which is "all occurrences"

```
txt = "1 2 3 4 5"

x = txt.split(" ")
y = txt.split()

print(x)
print(y)
```

**Output**

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

**Continuing...**

With extra white spaces on the input there is difference in the behavior, in the first case the number of white spaces is ignored, and the second one, each white space is a separator.

```
txt2 = "1  2 3 4 5 6    "

w = txt2.split()
z = txt2.split(" ")

print(w)
print(z)
```

**Output**

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
['1', '', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '', '', '', '']
```